# Error on Web Service request: The top XML element 'parameters' from namespace '' references distinct types

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, wcf

I have the following service interface that I have imported using the Visual Studio tool (it is a WCF Web Service).

[Reference.cs](https://gist.github.com/rodrigokiller/513d2e662132882a2e7be2eb89a6b6e0)

But when I try to consume the service **AuthenticateJAAS** (execute the web service), I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The top XML element 'parameters' from namespace '' references distinct types XAFProject.Module.WS.MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersGetUserGroupsIn and XAFProject.Module.WS.MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersAuthenticateJAASIn. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element or types.

I cannot change the namespace or the element name 'parameters', as it is from a WSDL that cannot be changed (third party). When I remove the class **GetUserGroupsRequest** and related content from the Reference.cs, I can consume the web service **AuthenticateJAAS** without problems. The generated XML is:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <AuthenticateJAAS xmlns="http://services.senior.com.br">
      <user xmlns=""/>
      <password xmlns=""/>
      <encryption xmlns="">0</encryption>
      <parameters xmlns="">
        <flowInstanceID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <flowName xsi:nil="true"/>
        <pmUserName>******</pmUserName>
        <pmUserPassword>******</pmUserPassword>
      </parameters>
    </AuthenticateJAAS>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is there a way to use both methods/services (AuthenticateJAAS + GetUserGroupsRequest) without any error? I was thinking that maybe, if I use namespace prefixes, I could manage to use both services, I think.

Here is the part of the code that I initialize the client and execute the service:

```cs
sapiens_SyncMCWFUsersClient mCWFUsersClient = new sapiens_SyncMCWFUsersClient(); 
mcwfUsersAuthenticateJAASIn parameters = new mcwfUsersAuthenticateJAASIn();
parametrosEntrada.pmUserName = "******";
parametrosEntrada.pmUserPassword = "******";
parametrosEntrada.pmEncrypted = 0;
AuthenticateJAASRequest request = new AuthenticateJAASRequest("", "", 0, parameters); 
AuthenticateJAASResponse response = mCWFUsersClient.AuthenticateJAAS(request);
```

Comment: Xml serialization is hard to debug.  You are on the right track.  Best way is like what you are doing is to comment out the  GetUserGroupsRequest class.  Now add back in and comment out all the methods inside  GetUserGroupsRequest.  Then add back in the commented section one at a time until you get another error.  Continue commenting and uncommenting properties until you find the one causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. Do you know if its possible to add namespaces prefix in that Reference.cs?

Comment: The fix should be in parent here : MCWFUsers.GetUserGroupsResponse GetUserGroups(MCWFUsers.GetUserGroupsRequest request);

Answer (score 0):

So far, I solved my problem by doing the following in the Reference.cs file.
`[System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=3, Name = "parameters")]`. Then, I changed the field name to anything but "parameter". In this case `public MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersGetUserGroupsIn parametersGetUserGroups;`
That means that this will not reference distinct types inside cs file.

I changed this:

```
 [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetUserGroups", WrapperNamespace="http://services.senior.com.br", IsWrapped=true)]
    public partial class GetUserGroupsRequest
    {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=0)]
        public string user;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=1)]
        public string password;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=2)]
        public int encryption;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=3)]
        public MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersGetUserGroupsIn parameters;
        
        public GetUserGroupsRequest()
        {
        }
        
        public GetUserGroupsRequest(string user, string password, int encryption, MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersGetUserGroupsIn parameters)
        {
            this.user = user;
            this.password = password;
            this.encryption = encryption;
            this.parameters = parameters;
        }
    }
```

to this

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.0.3")]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="GetUserGroups", WrapperNamespace="http://services.senior.com.br", IsWrapped=true)]
    public partial class GetUserGroupsRequest
    {
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=0)]
        public string user;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=1)]
        public string password;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=2)]
        public int encryption;
        
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace= "", Order=3, Name = "parameters")]
        public MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersGetUserGroupsIn parametersGetUserGroups;
        
        public GetUserGroupsRequest()
        {
        }
        
        public GetUserGroupsRequest(string user, string password, int encryption, MCWFUsers.mcwfUsersGetUserGroupsIn parameters)
        {
            this.user = user;
            this.password = password;
            this.encryption = encryption;
            this.parametersGetUserGroups = parameters;
        }
    }
```

---

Edit:
Nope, that didn't solve it, unfortunately.
I will keep trying.